# iOS - Distribution certificates Error

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to deploy to iOS but getting the following error:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "Error
>   Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=1 \"No certificate for team
>   'Company Name' matching '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer' found\"
>   UserInfo={IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorSpecifier=3rd
>   Party Mac Developer Installer, NSLocalizedDescription=No certificate
>   for team 'Company Name' matching '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer'
>   found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Specify a different signing
>   certificate for \"signingCertificate\" in your Export Options property
>   list.,
>   IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorTeam=,
>   IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorPlatform=com.apple.platform.iphoneos, IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorAction=5}"

I recently had apple modify my account to be a company developer and not a user, I think this is the problem but not sure how to resolve this now. I have generated all new certificates and provisions but still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't you enabled the automatic signing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix it. Something to do with Delphi still.

The project even though it is set to build for IOS iphones and has been deploying and developing fine, but when I deploy it thinks im deploying for Mac Apps.

I created a new project and re-added all of my files back to it and the issue has gone away. Something about that project makes the deployment think its going to Mac App so its looking for a provisioning file for that.

Comment: For anyone else coming across this problem, re-creating the project also worked for me. I really should have kept a backup so I could do a compare. I am now, so if it happens again I can diagnose it better.

Comment: I've also seen this problem, noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824554/delphi-10-2-3-e0776-exporting-ios-app-for-distribution

I'm having difficulty adding my deployed files into a new project but hopefully when I figure that out it'll start deploying correctly for me as well.

Comment: I've tried creating a new project and re-adding all of my files but it did not work. I get the same PAServer errors mentioning my '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer'.

Comment: Not sure, i started a new project, only brought across my pas files, nothing relating to project files or dprs, complete fresh start. Then setup all the project options from scratch for the provisioning etc... and it worked. I submitted it to Embarcadero for bug fixing but dont think it was resolved.

Comment: It may be related to the way I was handling custom changes to the Info.plist file. I decided to put my additions in the info.plist.TemplateiOS.XML file instead of creating my own custom file and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I had problems with that too I cannot set the version numbers I have I manually change in the final release the template won’t work either. Honestly Delphi is hopeless I have now decided to redo the project from scratch in xamarin it’s been so much better

Answer (score 0):

You Should check bundle name of your project. It seems you haven't yet 'Company Name' in bundle setting. if you are working on Unity3d than check build setting, if you are working on xcode then check its bundleid settings.

bundle name should be matched with your provisioning settings that you have created on apple developer site.

Comment: it does, i changed the company name to hide the real one

Comment: i can develop and test fine so i know that part is ok, i just cant deploy

Comment: Okay, but error log say that it seems doesn't match with bundle and provisioning file so did you try to deploy with same machine or using jenkins or another machine?

Comment: different machine using delphi PAServer. The bundleIds match, if they dont i actually get a different error to this