# Delphi 10.2.3 E0776 exporting iOS app for Distribution

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Two days ago, I was able to create an export of this iOS app and successfully submit it to Apple's TestFlight with Delphi 10.2.3 and Xcode 9.2.

Now, when deploying for the Application store, I get these error messages:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2018-04-13 13:44:47.524 xcodebuild[2598:310919] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/vs/z_nqsyqs6k3_h3jljhlxtz5c0000gn/T/COWMobileBuild20_2018-04-13_13-44-47.522.xcdistributionlogs'.
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2018-04-13 13:44:47.817 xcodebuild[2598:310919] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fa332dc2940>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776     "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=1 \"No certificate for team 'Bookup Corp.' matching '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer' found\" UserInfo={IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorSpecifier=3rd Party Mac Developer Installer, NSLocalizedDescription=No certificate for team 'Bookup Corp.' matching '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer' found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Specify a different signing certificate for \"signingCertificate\" in your Export Options property list., IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorTeam=<IDEProvisioningBasicTeam 0x7fa332dbaaa0: teamID: 6J8PUT9BW8, teamName: Bookup Corp.>, IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorPlatform=com.apple.platform.iphoneos, IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorAction=5}"
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: exportArchive: No certificate for team 'Bookup Corp.' matching '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer' found**

Why would it mention "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer"?

Unless Xcode is updating itself, nothing has changed other than improvements to the code of the project. Xcode is 9.2.

The app deploys without issues to an iPad, in both Debug and Release modes.

Comment: Sounds like something you should be asking Embarcadero about.

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20371

Comment: This issue is also in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881515/ios-distribution-certificates-error

I tried the suggested answer there of beginning with a new blank project but the PAServer errors persist.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell, this issue came up due to custom changes to the Info.plist file (adding TrueType fonts).

Adding the custom key pairs to info.plist.TemplateiOS.XML seemed to get around the issue.